# How to make import org.scalacheck.Gen possible in console/Scala REPL?

Tags: scala, sbt, scalacheck

I'm trying to run [ScalaCheck](http://www.scalacheck.org/) on REPL.

So I made an sbt project with the following `build.sbt`:

```
name := "Trying out ScalaCheck"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.2"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.11.5" % "test"

resolvers +=
  "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
```

Then, I typed `reload` and `updated` to get the library.

Finally, after running `console`, I tried to import `Gen` via:

```
scala> import org.scalacheck.Gen
<console>:7: error: object scalacheck is not a member of package org
       import org.scalacheck.Gen
                  ^
```

Looking at the [docs](http://www.scalacheck.org/files/scalacheck_2.11-1.11.5-api/#org.scalacheck.Gen), I'm not sure why I can't perform this import.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You added Scalacheck to the `test` scope, so it is available only within it. You should use `test:console` sbt command instead. See sbt [Scopes](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Scopes.html) docs for details.